# Issues to set minimum size of windows using WM_GETMINMAXINFO

Tags: c#, c++

I want to set different `minimum` and `maximum` dimensions for parent and child `window`. But when I try following set of codes, It set the same dimension for both `windows`.

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        { 

        MINMAXINFO* mmi = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam;
        DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWL_STYLE ) ;
        DWORD dwExStyle = GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE ) ;
        RECT rc1 = { 0, 0, 400, 400 } ;
        AdjustWindowRectEx( &rc1, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle );
        mmi->ptMinTrackSize.x = rc1.right - rc1.left;
        mmi->ptMinTrackSize.y = rc1.bottom - rc1.top;
        RECT rc2 = { 0, 0, 2560, 1920 };
        AdjustWindowRectEx( &rc2, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle );
        mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.x = rc2.right - rc2.left;
        mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.y = rc2.bottom - rc2.top;
        return 0;

    }
```

Please suggest me how I can set different values of `minimum` and `maximum` size for parent and child `window`.

Comment: Note that child window's coordinates are relative to parent, not absolute to screen.

Comment: Actually we are using above code in "Chromium embedded framework " . So we are getting problem in child window. I am new in this development, can you please help..Thanks

Comment: You have to process `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` independently in parent and child window.